# How can I see the transactions which move funds from a destroyed contract?

Tags: etherscan, internal-transactions, selfdestruct

I got this external [account](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x4c50a4cf1bd11ed1de4a3f66171aa3906cbc2590) from which I called a function of this [contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x69c4fe83f2ed228dfd55f030df885a20c5aae747dad9b49083eb36ca74226573) which subsequently called `selfdestruct` and sent all the funds to the caller.

Where can I see the tx making this transfer? There's no internal transactions tab in the external account's page, but there is [one](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x69c4fe83f2ed228dfd55f030df885a20c5aae747dad9b49083eb36ca74226573#internal) in the tx page. However, it displays `0 Ether`, although the external account was actually funded with 0.03 ETH.

Comment: I suspect it's just a rinkeby issue, and etherscan is not parsing it to the same level as they do for mainnet. Can you try again on ropsten? It's the closest to the mainnet in many forms, including in etherscan's support for extracting data.